# Integrating Google Tag Manager with Firebase in Android Project

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to integrate Google Tag Manager with Firebase for an Android Project. Am getting this error "No container asset found in /assets/containers. checking top level /assets directory for containers assets".

[image]

I have created app/main/assets/containers folder as mentioned in Google's guide "https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5/"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your assets folder should be inside app/

`app/assets/container/`

This is a pretty good guide to implementing GTM in Android apps

https://www.tatvic.com/blog/implement-google-tag-manager-v5-android-application/